# storing files on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3

I am developing an app where user will upload multiple images along with some other data like name address etc.

I am using MEAN stack for development, So I have some questions regarding this:

How should I store image data in my db, like what information should I save in my db ?

I have read that we can use GridFS by mongodb. But my images would be of max 5MB in size. So what should I use simple fs by node or gridfs by mongodb ?

What is the need of storing file data on amazon s3, can't I just save base64 string into my database ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem at all if the database is dedicated to storing the images. If you have other data in it, you might have to consider memory usage of loading the images and its impact on other operations